# Unexpected PHP-CURL output

Tags: post, php-curl

I'm trying to figure out why the following code still output on the commandline, even though there is no `echo` or `print_r` or `var_dump` command at the end. I want to get the output in a variable for further processing, but the `$result` variable has only boolean data type.

```
$data_string = '{"query":"{  ethereum(network: bsc) {    arguments(      smartContractAddress: {is: \"0xBCfCcbde45cE874adCB698cC183deBcF17952812\"}      smartContractEvent: {is: \"PairCreated\"}      argument: {not: \"pair\"}      options: {desc: \"block.height\", limit: 10}    ) {      block {        height        timestamp {          unixtime        }      }      argument {        name        type      }      reference {        address        smartContract {          currency {            name          }        }      }    }  }}","variables":"{}"}';
$headers = array('Content-Type: application/json', 'X-API-KEY: BQYI5KOkokFE3CBqPfQvldOhXwVKWEf8' );
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graphql.bitquery.io/' );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
//Output displayed at the command line without me specifically print/echo it ???
```

Anyone can help me to get the output to the variable `$result` correctly? Right now the output that I want is just displayed directly on the commandline

Answer (score 0):

CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false

try adding this parameter